# Не приходят push уведомления. FCM

Tags: android, firebase, android-notification, push-уведомления

Появилась необходимость реализовать push уведомления.

Прописал в манифесте сервис:

```
 <service
     android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
     </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

Сам класс у меня выглядит так:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

     Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

     NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.mipmap.icon))
            .setContentTitle(this.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

В чем собственно дело:

 У меня устройство на котором я провожу дебаггинг приложения, на нем все успешно приходит(android marshmallow). Пробую на другом устройстве(android 4.1, 4.2.2, 5.1) на них вообще глухо. Даже когда приложение запущено, уведомления не приходят.

Подскажите, в чем проблема, ведь на моем устройстве приходит. Библиотеки, все подключены корректно. Может быть с версиями API прогадал?

Comment: А как вы отправляете уведомление?

Comment: Через консоль firebase

Comment: А на этих устройствах какая версия Google Play Services? должна быть 9.6.1 или выше. Если ниже, то пуши не будут работать.

Comment: @miha_dev, а что значит "не будут работать"? Вылетит? Или откроет окно об обновлении сервисов? А если устройство без гаппсов вообще?

Comment: Вылетать не будет. Просто не придут. Окна не будет. Просто ничего не произойдет. Так как ваше устройство не зарегистрируется как приемник пушей.
Без гаппсов точно работать не будет

Answer (score 0):

Такое ощущение, что у вас проблема с правами. Попробую предположить:

1. Разные имена пакетов в приложении и в консоли разработчика. Это нужно проверить первым делом. Подробнее [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351354/firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-not-received-by-device).
2. В градле не прописано применение плагина для гугл служб

   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
3. Удалить приложение и скачать его(установить) как это было сделано для устройств android 4.1, 4.2.2, 5.1. Далее проверить лог на предмет ошибок.
4. Воспользоваться данной [ссылкой](https://www.internetfaqs.net/sc/gcm/) для проверки хождения  уведомлений.

Answer (score 0):

У меня на эмуляторе на андроиде всё прекрасно работало изначально. Поставил на дебаг свой LeEco Le2 x620 (прошитый на русскую прошивку) и ни одного уведомления, сервис Play был версии 8.4.x. У коллеги на LeEco Le2 x527 всё отрабатывало прекрасно (версия сервиса Play 8.6.x). Я обновился до 11 версии сервисов Play и в общем-то всё заработало. Ещё пришлось устройство перезагрузить, чтобы работало всё стабильно. Так же не забывайте делать приложение защищенным, тогда уведомления работают даже если выгрузить полностью приложение из оперативы (не знаю насколько это стабильно и долго будет работать, тестирую).

Comment: Обнаружилась проблема. Как только выключаю инет и снова включаю, уведомления перестают приходить. Как минимум на моём устройстве. Переустановить или перезапустить приложение - бесполезно. Срабатывают уведомления только после перезагрузки устройства. Не знаю как с этим бороться, не знаю в чём именно проблема и мне очень интересно как KateMobile, WhatsApp и прочие получают данные когда висят в трее, без перебоев, стабильно.